# Is there a way to filter columns in Python using multiple data types in condition?

Tags: python, dataframe

**I am trying to filter columns based on numeric and categorical data types and then create separate list for each for Regression Problems.**

*Problem is i am not able to do this using .isin(['object','O'])*

**List of Columns:**

Manufacturer              157 non-null object

Model                     157 non-null object

Sales_in_thousands        157 non-null float64

four_year_resale_value    121 non-null float64

Vehicle_type              157 non-null object

Price_in_thousands        155 non-null float64

Engine_size               156 non-null float64

Horsepower                156 non-null float64

Wheelbase                 156 non-null float64

Width                     156 non-null float64

Latest_Launch             157 non-null object

Power_perf_factor         155 non-null float64

I want to do it using .isin([]) as multiple options can be passed in the list but its not working

#### Below code doesn't work and I am looking for solutions for this code

```
df.dtypes.loc[df.dtypes.isin(['object','O'])]
```

#### Below code works but I dont like this way of writing code as if there are too many options then this code can get unnecessarily long & messy

```
df.dtypes.loc[(df.dtypes == ('object')) | (df.dtypes == ('O'))]
```

#### Output:

Manufacturer     object

Model            object

Vehicle_type     object

Latest_Launch    object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a handy helper function for exactly what you're trying to do, [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['O'])

df.select_dtypes(exclude=['O'])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for !!

Comment: Yeah, I was so happy when I discovered this method! Don't forget to accept the answer with the check mark if it helped you out.

Comment: Yeah, its a great way to do the job in just one step. I have checked the up grey marker. Hope that's what you were referring to. I am not sure as I am new here!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for accepting, and welcome to SO!